# Placeholder Fields - Django CMS

Tags: python, html, django

I can't get those placeholder fields to work.

This is my model:

```
    class Category(models.Model):
        class Meta:
             verbose_name = "Kategorie"
             verbose_name_plural = "Kategorien"
        header = PlaceholderField('header')
```

And this is my views:

```
    def rooms_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request, "rooms/rooms-list.html", locals())
```

If I know try to render it like so:

```
   {% render_placeholder category.header %}
```

Nothing happens at all...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see all your code but, in the template do you do a loop over your categories?

something like

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% render_placeholder category.header %}
{% endfor %}
```

also, check if {{ categories }} is available by rendering it out just like that.

add this to the top of the template {% load cms_tags %}
and do the rendering as I have added above.

Comment: @Martin Zangerl you should add a comment under my answer. This way we can communicate. Instead of you placing a question which is better to be placed below the answer in the comment section.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that now :)

Answer (score 0):

If i render it out, I get:
<QuerySet [<Category: test>]>

And no, I dont use a loop.

This is my admin.py:

```
    class CategoryAdmin(PlaceholderAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = "__all__"


    admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

But also I can not see something about the placeholder in the frontend... weird

Thank you very much for your quick response.